# xml rpc client and server

Tags: python-3.x, xmlrpcclient, simplexmlrpcserver

i tried to connect this  xmlRPCClient code  with this server but it didn't work even i sued the same localhost and called the right user  .. 
 I'm using python3 to get finally a method to login for a wireless-hart manager ..
I would like to see the xml response.

So basically I would like to send the following as my request to the server
Any solutions ??

xmlRPCServer.py :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Adapted from https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCServer
# Provide a test for valid username
# Provide a "database" lookup from username to user UUID (and status)

userDatabase = {
   "ahmed": {"UUID": "1111111", "activeStatus" : True },
   "jane":  {"UUID": "1111112", "activeStatus" : False },
   "alec": {"UUID": "1111113", "activeStatus" : True },
}

from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from xmlrpc.client import Fault

def userExists(u):
    """Does a user exist?"""
    return (u in userDatabase)

def getActiveUserUUID(u):
    """Get the UUID for given active user"""
    return getUserUUIDbyState(u, "active")

def getUserUUIDbyStatus(u, s):
    """Get the UUID for a given user, any status"""
    if userExists(u) and userDatabase[u]["activeStatus"] == s:
        return {"user": u, "UUID": userDatabase[u]["UUID"]}
    else:
        raise Fault(1, "No {status} user {user} found".format(status = "active" if s else   "inactive", user=u))

def getUserAllDetails(u):
    """Get all the user details for a given user"""
    if userExists(u):
        result = userDatabase[u]
        result.update({"user": u})
        return result
    else:
        raise Fault(1, "No user {} found".format(u))

def getAllUsersByStatus(s):
    """List all the users, filtered by their active status"""
    # NOTE: Normally it's bad practice to return a potentially huge list.
    result = []
    for user, info in userDatabase.items():
        if info["activeStatus"] == s:
            info.update({"user": user})
            result.append(info)

        if len(result) == 0:
            raise Fault(2, "No users found with active status of {}".format(s))

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/users',)

    # Create server
    with SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 9089),requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
        server.register_introspection_functions()
        server.register_function(userExists)
        server.register_function(getActiveUserUUID)
        server.register_function(getUserUUIDbyStatus)
        server.register_function(getUserAllDetails)
        server.register_function(getAllUsersByStatus)
        # Run the server's main loop
        print( "Starting API server on 8080")
        server.serve_forever()
```

xmlRPCClient.py:

````py
import http.client

request_body = b"<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<methodCall>\n<methodName>getUserAllDetails</methodName>\n<params>\n<param>\n<value><string>alec</string></value>\n</param>\n</params>\n</methodCall>\n"
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('localhost:9089')
connection.putrequest('POST', '/')
connection.putheader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
connection.putheader('User-Agent', 'Python-xmlrpc/3.5')
connection.putheader("Content-Length", str(len(request_body)))
connection.endheaders(request_body)

print(connection.getresponse().read())
```py3
````

Comment: Hi Skander, can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? Was there an error/exception, did nothing happen, did something unexpected happen? Please include that information as an edit in your question.

Comment: it works when i run the server with (python3 server.py) in the cmd
But with the client didn't work